# Cannot save changes in file under Git version control

Tags: windows, git

I forked and cloned a project from GitHub and I can make changes to all files but one.
It's `.xml`. When I make changes and hit the save button, the file reverts back to its original state.

I've done `git config core.fileMode false` but to no avail. I've also checked the file permissions and it's `-rw-r--r--`. Same as other files I can edit.

Please, how can I solve this problem?
The last time, I had to go to Git web and make the changes there before pulling.

Comment: *"the file reverts back to its original state"* - I'm pretty convinced, that no file in the universe has such powers. It's the tool you are using that reverts the contents. So, incidentally, what tool are you using?

Comment: I've used Ecplise, VScode, even notepad.

Comment: Hm... Notepad. Now that is Windows-only, right? How does that relate to file permissions with the `-rw-r--r--` format?

Comment: @IInspectable I've not tested on any other OS. The file just gets back to its original state when I save and restart the editor.

Comment: I'm not following. You are saying, that at least one of your editors runs on Windows, but you bring up non-Windows file permissions. So are you on Windows or are you not on Windows? And if you are, what's with those file permissions? How did you observe those (that do not make much sense in Windows)?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm on Windows 10. `ls -l` shows me file permissions.

Comment: `ls` is not a valid command in the Windows command prompt. Are you using the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I realized the file I was editing is in a directory in the `.gitignore`.
So maybe git was undoing the changes I was making.